# How to Normalize the relational schema?

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

Consider the following Relational Schema:

[image]

I am trying to fully Normalize (In Third Normal Form) and determine the functional dependencies. However, with endless research, I cannot get around on how to:

1. Fully Normalize the Relational Schema
2. Determine the Functional Dependencies

How would I go about this?

Comment: One might be tempted to ask 'Why `adressline2` in Manager', but that's nit-picking. More seriously, are managers employees or not? There's an awful lot of repetition between Employee and Manager tables. There are 4 different ways of representing addresses (3 with the misspelling fixed); is that ideal? Otherwise, it isn't too bad a schema. Maybe it would be worth using BranchID instead of BranchName as the joining field, but that's at most an optimization and possibly even a pessimization. It's not entirely clear why there's an EmployeeID in the Customer table, but there are possible reasons.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a textbook/reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs. Google with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

Answer (score 1):

1. An employee can be a customer, and may become a manager one day. Use the Party Model. "Employee" or "Customer" should be a role played by a Party. A Party hasMany Roles
2. People can have no address, one address, or multiple addresses. People can share the same address. Use an Address table, and a PersonAddress junction table. Same with phone numbers.
3. You'll probably want to have individual customers and organization customers (companies or shared accounts). Use the Party Model.
4. Why does Branch not use a BranchId when all the other tables use id columns?
5. Are you sure a Customer is assigned to an Employee? What if the employee is on vacation?
6. Why "city" and "town" in Branch?